# Replace 2 lines in a file using sed command

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I try to delete the comma on the next-to-last line:

> ```
> {
>   "subject" : {
>     "value" : "http://d-nb.info/gnd/1-2",
>     "type" : "uri"
>     },
>   "predicate" : {
>     "value" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
>     "type" : "uri"
>     },
>   "object" : {
>     "value" : "http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#SeriesOfConferenceOrEvent",
>     "type" : "uri"
>     }
>   },
> {
> ```

And I am using this command:

```
<test2.file sed '/^\s*\},$/ { N; s/^\s*\},\n\{/^\s*\}\n\{/ }'
```

I expect the output should be like that:

> ```
> {
>   "subject" : {
>     "value" : "http://d-nb.info/gnd/1-2",
>     "type" : "uri"
>     },
>   "predicate" : {
>     "value" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
>     "type" : "uri"
>     },
>   "object" : {
>     "value" : "http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#SeriesOfConferenceOrEvent",
>     "type" : "uri"
>     }
>   }
> {
> ```

But it returns an error.

> sed: -e expression #1, char 42: Unmatched {

Does anybody know what's wrong with it? Thx.

P.S., Here is the end of the file:

> ```
> {
>   "subject" : {
>     "value" : "http://d-nb.info/gnd/1060867974",
>     "type" : "uri"
>     },
>   "predicate" : {
>     "value" : "http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#preferredNameEntityForThePerson",
>     "type" : "uri"
>     },
>   "object" : {
>     "value" : "_:genid12768016",
>     "type" : "bnode"
>     }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't escape `{ or }` in your pattern/address part. sed uses BRE by default. With BRE, chars like `{ ( + ..` don't have special meaning, you have to escape them to give them special meaning.

In your case, you want to match literal `{ or }`, then don't escape them.

#### EDIT

I guess you want to remove the last comma, so that change:

```
...
 },
{
```

into

```
...
 }
{
```

then you can try:

```
awk -v RS='\0' '7+gsub(/,\s*{/,"\n{")' file
```

test with your file:

```
kent$  awk -v RS='\0' '7+gsub(/,\s*{/,"\n{")' f
{
  "subject" : {
    "value" : "http://d-nb.info/gnd/1-2",
    "type" : "uri"
    },
  "predicate" : {
    "value" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
    "type" : "uri"
    },
  "object" : {
    "value" : "http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#SeriesOfConferenceOrEvent",
    "type" : "uri"
    }
  }
{
```

Comment: Thx, now I chaged to this:    <test2.file sed '/^\s*},$/ { N; s/^\s*},\n{/^\s*}\n{/ }'  Nothing happened, what's wrong with my new reivison?

Comment: @hui can you paste the desired output so that I can do a test for you?

Comment: Sure. 

    {
      "subject" : {
        "value" : "http://d-nb.info/gnd/1-2",
        "type" : "uri"
        },
      "predicate" : {
        "value" : "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type",
        "type" : "uri"
        },
      "object" : {
        "value" : "http://d-nb.info/standards/elementset/gnd#SeriesOfConferenceOrEvent",
        "type" : "uri"
        }
      }
    {

Comment: @hui I mean paste in your question within code block, so that people can read. not in comment. ;-)

Comment: @hui I added the awk one-liner in my answer, check if it is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, just come back from lunch, right now. 对不起，我刚才吃饭没看到。 Now I paste the expected output in the question .). Is there anyway to do it using sed command?

Comment: @hui sed can do it too. however awk is easier for your requirement.

Comment: Thx for your solution. But I still can't understand the meaning of '\0' and 7, and if this text is just a part of a large file, I mean, if there the comma I want to delete is not on the next-to-last line, can I still use this one-line command?

Comment: `\0` is load the whole file into memory as a "single line", then do the substitution on the whole text. the `gsub()` could return 0, in case no match found, we want to print anyway, no matter the substitution is successfully done or not. so I added a non-zero number, let awk print the text. It should work for your larger file, you can check before and after by a diff. @hui

Comment: there is a problem that I try a large file and the last two lines of the file are : }\n } . And when I used the awk command then two lines disappeared.

Comment: @hui the awk line shouldn't remove the lines. try to make a reproduce-able example, then we can check what was going wrong.

Comment: I put the end of the file in the question, and after I used the awk command, the last two braces just disappeared...

Comment: @hui I just tested my awk one-liner on your example text. since there is no `}, (linebreak) {` in your text, the output is same as input. but no lines were removed.

Comment: that is strange. Sorry I found that not the last two lines disappeared, it turned out that the command stopped at some place near the end. I will upload the file to dropbox, so u can test the whole file.

Comment: here is the link to the whole file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/38ggfiu0e7y7ed8/json.ntriples.new.gz?dl=0

Comment: @hui try extracting to a reproduce-able example, I can check what's wrong with the codes. However I won't download a 1.3Gib file and do test for you... sorry. Or you can consider other solutions.

Comment: sorry about the large file. I will consider other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the indentation to recognize the right line?

`sed 's/^  },/  }/'`

Comment: The command in the answer worked for me, when I copy-pasted the example you provided into running `sed`.